# How to change stereo sound when cursor moving?

Tags: javascript, html, audio

when I visite the website: https://jviewz.com , I noticed that the stereo sound changes when moving the cursor left or right (best experience when wearing headphones). However, this effect of the website only works on GG Chrome browser.
I found a similar demo here: https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/stereo-panner-node/ and it works fine on all browsers, however it is being controlled by the input range slide. I'm wondering if there's a way to control this with the mouse pointer similar to a web page: https://jviewz.com? Thanks for any solutions.

Comment: As far as getting cursor position is concerned that is very simple to do. You just need to bind on mousemove event, it would fire whenever user moves his mouse even a tiny bit and in the handler you would get the fresh coordinates. Now rest is upto you how to use those X and Y coordinates, storing them in some variable, calculate the distance of cursor from (0,0) origin etc. [Ref](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Actually, i am looking for help with the code that controls the stereo sound of a website with a mouse pointer like the website: https://jviewz.com. Because I'm not a professional JS programmer. I could only find the simple solution provided here: https://mdn.github.io/webaudio-examples/stereo-panner-node/